# Cannot find name 'classes'. TS2304?

Tags: reactjs, class

I want to customize my appbar size on react Mui(currently using v4, but I get an error everytime I try to create a style.

My current Code

```
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, Box, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Navbar.css'

const styles ={
    customizeToolbar: {
        minHeight: 36
    }
};

function Navbar(){
    return(
        <AppBar position='sticky' >
            <Toolbar variant='dense' style={classes.customizeToolbar} >

            </Toolbar>
            
        </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to customize the theme, you need to use the `ThemeProvider` component in order to inject a theme into your application. You must create styles with `makeStyles`, then you can create variable `classes` and use it in jsx with `className` not `style`. If you want customize not only `Navbar` but all components you can set `ThemeProvider` in index.js

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    customizeToolbar: {
        minHeight: 36
    }
  })
);
const theme = createTheme();

function Navbar(){
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppBar position='sticky' >
            <Toolbar variant='dense' className={classes.customizeToolbar} >

            </Toolbar>
            
        </AppBar>
       </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hello, I still got the same error :
Cannot find name 'classes'.  TS2304

    19 |
    20 |             </Toolbar>
  > 21 |             <Toolbar variant='dense' style={classes.customizeToolbar}>
       |                                             ^

Comment: Have you ThemeProvider ? https://mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider If you wish to customize the theme, you need to use the ThemeProvider component in order to inject a theme into your application. https://mui.com/styles/api/#createstyles-styles-styles

Comment: Also use `className={classes.customizeToolbar}` instead of `style={classes.customizeToolbar}`

Comment: It worked, thanks!!!

Comment: If it help you check answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, Box, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Navbar.css'

const styles ={
  customizeToolbar: {
    minHeight: 36
  }
};

function Navbar(){
  return(
    <AppBar position='sticky' >
        <Toolbar variant='dense' style={styles.customizeToolbar} >

        </Toolbar>
        
    </AppBar>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```